# How to update numpy array based on pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, lookup-tables

I have a numpy array with thousands of rows and columns, and I'm wondering how to update each value based on the values in a pandas DataFrame.

For example, let's say my array contains a list of years (here's an incredibly small sample just to give you the basic idea):

```
[[2020, 2015, 2017],
 [2015, 2016, 2016],
 [2019, 2018, 2020]]
```

I want to change each value in the array to "Lat" based on the "Year". So if my pandas dataframe looks like this:

| Year | Lat | Lon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 37.2 | 103.45 |
| 2019 | 46.1 | 107.82 |
| 2018 | 35.2 | 101.45 |
| 2017 | 38.6 | 110.62 |
| 2016 | 29.1 | 112.73 |
| 2015 | 33.8 | 120.92 |

Then the output array should look like:

```
[[37.2, 33.8, 38.6],
 [33.8, 29.1, 29.1],
 [46.1, 35.2, 37.2]]
```

If my dataset were truly this small, it wouldn't be a problem, but considering I have millions of values in the array and thousands of values in the DataFrame, I'm a little overwhelmed on how to go about this efficiently.

**Update:**

Perhaps my question might be a bit more complicated than I anticipated. Rather than matching up the years, I'm matching up GPS time, so the numbers don't match up as nicely. Is there a way to take a number in the array and match it up to the closest value in the DataFrame column? In reality, my array would look more like this:

```
[[2019.99, 2015.2, 2017.1],
 [2015.33, 2016.01, 2015.87],
 [2019.2, 2018.3, 2020.00]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe setting `Year` as index and using `at` (or `loc`) would help

```
# Data
arr = np.array([[2020, 2015, 2017], [2015, 2016, 2016], [2019, 2018, 2020]])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': {0: 2020, 1: 2019, 2: 2018, 3: 2017, 4: 2016, 5: 2015},
                   'Lat': {0: 37.2, 1: 46.1, 2: 35.2, 3: 38.6, 4: 29.1, 5: 33.8},
                   'Lon': {0: 103.45, 1: 107.82, 2: 101.45, 3: 110.62, 4: 112.73, 5: 120.92}})

df = df.set_index("Year")
np.array([df.loc[years, "Lat"] for years in arr])
# array([[37.2, 33.8, 38.6],
#        [33.8, 29.1, 29.1],
#        [46.1, 35.2, 37.2]])
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful - thank you so much for your time! Perhaps my question might be a bit more complicated than I anticipated. Rather than matching up the years, I'm matching up GPS time, so the numbers don't match up as nicely. Is there a way to take a number in the array and match it up to the closest value in the dataframe column? Or even return NA if no match could be made?

Answer (score 1):

[np.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) can be used to detect the unique values in the `years` list, then `return_inverse=True` can be set to return the indices necessary to recreate the input array.

We can use this in conjunction with [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) to create a Series of values that can be converted [to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html). Then the results of the indices from [np.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) can be used with this array of latitude values to select the necessary values. A final [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) can be used to get the array in the correct form.

```
u, inv = np.unique(years, return_inverse=True)
result = (
    df.set_index('Year')['Lat'].reindex(u).to_numpy()[inv].reshape(years.shape)
)
```

`result`:

```
[[37.2 33.8 38.6]
 [33.8 29.1 29.1]
 [46.1 35.2 37.2]]
```

---

Results from [np.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

```
u, inv = np.unique(years, return_inverse=True)

u=array([2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020])
inv=array([5, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 5])
```

The `Lat` column with the Year as the index:

```
df.set_index('Year')['Lat']

Year
2020    37.2
2019    46.1
2018    35.2
2017    38.6
2016    29.1
2015    33.8
Name: Lat, dtype: float64
```

[reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html)ed to match the order from [np.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
df.set_index('Year')['Lat'].reindex(u)

Year
2015    33.8
2016    29.1
2017    38.6
2018    35.2
2019    46.1
2020    37.2
Name: Lat, dtype: float64
```

NumPy indexing to select from this new Series:

```
df.set_index('Year')['Lat'].reindex(u).to_numpy()[inv]

array([37.2, 33.8, 38.6, 33.8, 29.1, 29.1, 46.1, 35.2, 37.2])
```

The final [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) to match the initial input `years` array dimensions:

```
df.set_index('Year')['Lat'].reindex(u).to_numpy()[inv].reshape(years.shape)

array([[37.2, 33.8, 38.6],
       [33.8, 29.1, 29.1],
       [46.1, 35.2, 37.2]])
```

---

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': [2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015],
    'Lat': [37.2, 46.1, 35.2, 38.6, 29.1, 33.8],
    'Lon': [103.45, 107.82, 101.45, 110.62, 112.73, 120.92]
})

years = np.array([[2020, 2015, 2017],
                  [2015, 2016, 2016],
                  [2019, 2018, 2020]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically mapping values across columns. One idea is to use indexing to locate the elements that need to be replaced for a given key, then replace them all at once. This takes one iteration for each key-value pair in the original data.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array([
    [2020, 2015, 2017],
    [2015, 2016, 2016],
    [2019, 2018, 2020],
])
b = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=float)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': [2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015],
    'Lat': [37.2, 46.1, 35.2, 38.6, 29.1, 33.8],
})

for k, v in df.set_index('Year')['Lat'].to_dict().items():
    b[a == k] = v
print(b)

# output:
# [[37.2 33.8 38.6]
#  [33.8 29.1 29.1]
#  [46.1 35.2 37.2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
df.set_index('Year').Lat.loc[arr.flatten()].to_numpy().reshape(arr.shape)
```

If you're going to do multiple operations like this you should call `set_index()` just once, perhaps with `inplace=True` if you want to modify the existing DataFrame rather than create a new one.

After that it's just a matter of giving `loc` a 1D array which it can use for efficient lookup of the `Lat` values, then reshaping the result to match the original `arr`.

This is similar to d.b's answer, but massively more efficient because it does not use Python `for` loops.

Comment: @jake_p: Updating your question to ask a different question is not going to work well.  I suggest you accept one of the answers here now and post a new question with what you're actually looking for.